# Servers Element in the OSS Spec

Tags: swashbuckle, swagger-codegen, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I would like to remove the server element of my specification that was generated since the last update. Can ma control this via the settings of how the JSON is generated?

I would like it to look like

```
 {
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "Dummy API",
    "version": "v1"
  },
  "paths": { ... } }
```

and not like

```
 { "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "info": {
    "title": "Core API",
    "version": "v1"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://myUrl...."
    }
  ],
  "paths": { ... } }
```

Comment: Post your code and the current config settings from which this OpenAPI definition is generated.